# Download .gz zipped .nc file from URL

Tags: r, gzip, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to download the Hadley Met Office sea ice dataset from their website.  The data is stored in a .nc format and has also been compressed in the .gz format.

I've tried the following, and I get errors with the last step:

```
library(ncdf4)
url <- "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST_ice.nc.gz" # dataset
tmp <- tempfile() # creating a temporary file for dataset
download.file(url, tmp) # download compressed dataset 
HadIce <- nc_open(filename = gzfile(tmp))

Error in nc_open(filename = gzfile(tmp)) : 
  Passed a filename that is NOT a string of characters!
```

How do I pass a filename for the uncompressed dataset?

UPDATE: I tried another approach that I found for opening .gz files, but it also resulted in error messages:

```
tmpdir <- tempdir()
url <- "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST_ice.nc.gz"
file <- basename(url)
download.file(url, file)
untar(file)

tar.exe: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
Warning message:
In untar(file) : ‘tar.exe -xf "HadISST_ice.nc.gz"’ returned error code 1
```

UPDATE #2: this approach seems to have some promise, but I have no idea how to access the .nc file once it's been uncompressed sinze

```
filez = "HadISST_ice.nc.gz"
url <- "https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST_ice.nc.gz"
zipped.file = download.file(url = url, destfile = filez) 
HadIce <- nc_open(gzip(filez))

Error in R_nc4_open: NetCDF: Unknown file format
Error in nc_open(gzip(filez)) : 
  Error in nc_open trying to open file HadISST_ice.nc.gz.gz (return_on_error= FALSE )
```